# nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Error: Could not deserialize

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303138
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:869) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:342) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3059) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1866) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1794) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1615) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.findFlights(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Entity class:

```
package com.shameem.flightreservation.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;
    private Date dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }

    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }

    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }

    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }

    public String getArrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }

    public void setArrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }

    public Date getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeparture(Date dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public Timestamp getEstimatedDepartureTime() {
        return estimatedDepartureTime;
    }

    public void setEstimatedDepartureTime(Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime) {
        this.estimatedDepartureTime = estimatedDepartureTime;
    }



}
```

Flight Repository class:

```
 package com.shameem.flightreservation.repos;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

    import com.shameem.flightreservation.entities.Flight;

    public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight,Long> {

        @Query("from Flight where departureCity= :departureCity and arrivalCity= :arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture= :dateOfDeparture")
        List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from,@Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);

    }
```

Flight Controller class:

```
package com.shameem.flightreservation.controllers;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.shameem.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.shameem.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/findFlights")
    public String findFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to,@RequestParam("departureDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") Date departureDate,ModelMap modelMap)
    {
        System.out.println(departureDate);
        List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findFlights(from,to,departureDate);

        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);

        return"displayFlight";

    }

}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Please help me why I am not able to fetch data from a database.

Here I am trying to pass the data to the repository from the controller in order to fetch data from database but while fetching data it shows an error that it could not deserialize even after implementing Serialization in the entity class

Comment: You specified `nativeQuery = true` in the `@Query`, which means the `value` must be a SQL statement starting with the `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: You set `nativeQuery = true`, but use a query that is not valid SQL (hint: SQL queries start with `select`, not with `from`.

Comment: After removing  `nativeQuery = true` I am getting a new error  `invalid stream header: 32303138`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an entire query, not just the `from` and `where` clauses:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from Flight where departureCity= :departureCity and arrivalCity= :arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture= :dateOfDeparture",nativeQuery = true)
// Here --------^
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * from Flight where departureCity= :departureCity and arrivalCity= :arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture= :dateOfDeparture",nativeQuery = true)
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from,@Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

**My thought is if we using column name camel case then database column should be in underscore like if we are using arrivalCity then
     Database base column arrival_city. So please check this way also.**

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * from Flight where departure_city= :departureCity and arrival_city= :arrivalCity and date_of_departure= :dateOfDeparture",nativeQuery = true)
List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from,@Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

Comment: after doing this, the previous error of `SQLException` has gone but new error arises  `nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize`, please help

Comment: Can you please provide full exception

Comment: I have edited the question at the top I have mentioned the whole error

Comment: Thanks, @Mathu my issue is resolved. I have imported the wrong package in my code, `import java.security.Timestamp` was get imported automatically but when I changed the wrong import to `import java.sql.Timestamp`; the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * from Flight  where DEPARTURE_CITY=:departureCity and ARRIVAL_CITY=:arrivalCity and DATE_OF_DEPARTURE=:dateOfDeparture", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, @Param("arrivalCity") String to,@Param("dateOfDeparture") Date departureDate);
```

once try this